# How to loop through code to compress multiple images rather than 1

Tags: php

I have the below code which works perfectly and compressing 1 image at a time, however, I would like to have this loop so that it can handle multiple images at any one time.

```
   <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="file-upload-wrapper">
         <input type="file" name="image" accept="images" multiple>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="upload" name="submit">
   </form>
```

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        
        $image_name=$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $tmp_name=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    
        $directory_name='uploads/'; //folder where image will upload
        $file_name=$directory_name.$image_name;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $file_name);
    
        $compress_file="og_optimised--".$image_name;        
        $compressed_img=$directory_name.$compress_file;
        $compress_image=compressImage($file_name,$compressed_img);    
        unlink($file_name); //delete original file

    }

    function compressImage($source_image,$compress_image) {
        
        $image_info=getimagesize($source_image);
        $compression_level = $_POST["compression"];
        
        if ($image_info['mime']=='image/jpeg') {
            $source_image=imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image);
            imagejpeg($source_image,$compress_image,60); //for jpeg or gif, it should be 0-100 
        }
        elseif ($image_info['mime']=='image/png') {
            $source_image=imagecreatefrompng($source_image);
            imagepng($source_image,$compress_image,3); //for png it should be 0 to 9
        }
        return $compress_image;
    }
    
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you :)

I have attempted to use a loop statement but cant seem to get it working, likely my lack of PHP knowledge.

Comment: You need to start by naming your file input field something like `name="image[]"` - without the square brackets, PHP will _overwrite_ multiple values for a GET/POST parameter, with the last one. And then you need to modify how you are looping over the data, because for a multiple file upload, PHP populates $_FILES with a different structure, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: Then you will get a `$_FILES['image']` which is an array, one per file